# Can I create database tables using controller in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, controller

How can i create database tables using controllers in laravel. Is there any way?

Actually I want to create a table using another table column values.

Eg:
I have two tables called table1 and table2.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>name</td>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>raj</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>john</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>sam</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I want the names as field names in table2

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>raj</td>
        <td>john</td>
        <td>sam</td>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And I want to create table2 using controller

Comment: Do you really want to create database tables or just html tables?

Comment: database tables

Comment: Although it may be possible to do so using the `Schema` facade and using `Schema::create()` i would never do it

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you show an example?

Comment: Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-tables

Comment: This is called a pivot table and you can generate them on the fly even in MySQL. There are dozens of questions regarding mysql pivot tables here on SO. Why would you want to create actual tables from the pivot? It would have to be updated every time when the underlying table is updated.

Comment: Thanks. Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->increments('id'); $table->string('name'); });   This worked for me. thank you @gbestard

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this? I would imagine there is a much better way to achieve what you want without creating a brand new table every time!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that!? I see no reasons!

Anyway you can use raw query in controller :

```
DB::raw(' CREATE TABLE . ..  ');
```